# Plotting 2 columns of a csv with matplotlib error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, graph

I am trying to make a simple bar graph out of a 2 column CSV file. One column is the x axis names, the other column is the actual data which will be used for the bars. The CSV looks like this:

```
count,team
21,group1
15,group2
63,group3
22,group4
42,group5
72,group6
21,group7
23,group8
24,group9
31,group10
32,group11
```

I am using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sampleData.csv",sep=",").set_index('count')

d = dict(zip(df.index,df.values.tolist()))

df.plot.bar(x = 'count', y = 'team')

print(d)
```

However, I get an error

> KeyError: 'count' from this line :
>   df.plot.bar(x = 'count', y = 'team')

I don't understand how there is an error for something that exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `count` as index, you just have a single column left in your DataFrame, i.e., `team`. Don't set the `count` as index and switch the order of x and y values for plotting the bar chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sampleData.csv", sep=",")
df.plot.bar(x = 'team', y = 'count')
```

[image]

**Matplotlib solution**

```
plt.bar(df['team'], df['count']) 
plt.xticks(rotation=45) # Just rotating for better visualizaton
```